# ¿Como obtener los resultados de una función que hace consultas sql que varian sobre las valores de un array?

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de listas y quiero convertirla en DataFrames. Por ejemplo aqui esta una lista :

```
[[{'count': 6L, 'eclipse_id': 11348}, {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11338},
{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11342}, {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11361},
{'count': 6L, 'eclipse_id': 11313}],
[[{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11374},{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11356},
{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11358}]]
```

#### El resultado esperado

Sería varios arrays según la lista dentro de la lista:

Primera matriz:

```
    count  eclipse_id
0       6     11348.0
1       1     11338.0
2       1     11342.0
3       1     11361.0
4       6     11313.0
```

Segunda matriz:

```
    count  eclipse_id
0       1     11374.0
1       1     11356.0
2       1     11358.0
```

Sería aún más maravilloso si se ordenó!

#### Mi intento

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
i = 0
for liste in listeGroupContentReactions:
    df_n[i] = pd.DataFrame(liste)
    i+1
```

Sin emargo me respuesta `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

El error completo es el siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-851a5559a58d> in <module>()
      6 i = 0
      7 for liste in listeGroupContentReactions:
----> 8     df_n[i] = pd.DataFrame(liste)
      9     i+1
     10 

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2427         else:
   2428             # set column
-> 2429             self._set_item(key, value)
   2430 
   2431     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2494         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   2495         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 2496         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2497 
   2498         # check if we are modifying a copy

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   1646 
   1647     def _set_item(self, key, value):
-> 1648         self._data.set(key, value)
   1649         self._clear_item_cache()
   1650 

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in set(self, item, value, check)
   3716         except KeyError:
   3717             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 3718             self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
   3719             return
   3720 

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   3817 
   3818         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim,
-> 3819                            placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   3820 
   3821         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self._blknos[loc:]):

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   2717                      placement=placement, dtype=dtype)
   2718 
-> 2719     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
   2720 
   2721 # TODO: flexible with index=None and/or items=None

/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim, fastpath)
    113             raise ValueError('Wrong number of items passed %d, placement '
    114                              'implies %d' % (len(self.values),
--> 115                                              len(self.mgr_locs)))
    116 
    117     @property

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que un diccionario esta la unica solucion. Con los valores siguientes :

```
values = [[{'count': 6L, 'eclipse_id': 11348}, {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11338},
{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11342}, {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11361},
{'count': 6L, 'eclipse_id': 11313}],
[{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11374},{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11356},
{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 11358}]]
```

Podemos grabarlos :

```
dataFrameList = {}

i=0
for subList in values :
    dataFrameList[i] = pd.DataFrame(subList)
    dataFrameList[i] = dataFrameList[i].sort_values("count", ascending=False)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Marine1, te hago notar simplemente dos cosas, el valor de `values` está mal conformado, hay un `[` de más en el segundo resulset. Y por otro lado recuerda que puedes usar `for i, subList in enumerate(values)` para no tener que llevar un índice aparte. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muchas gracias por tus ideas. Intento hacerlo con una funcion [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84189/como-crear-una-funcion-transforma-en-lista-de-dataframes-un-array-de-lista-de-l])